# Excel activeX buttons require two clicks to call event

Tags: excel, vba

I have no idea what I've done, but when I add activex buttons to my sheet I have to click each one twice. The first click it simply gets focus (it briefly gets the cross/navigation style icon) then it puts the focus dots round it.

I then click it again and it finally calls the click event.

It does it for brand new buttons I add too. Macro buttons are ok.

I spotted this, but no answers:
[Excel ActiveX after Windows scaling, Objects require an 'extra' click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57915838/excel-activex-after-windows-scaling-objects-require-an-extra-click)

Comment: I also click the button on my userform slowly (say for a sec) .. https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/having-to-click-activex-button-twice-to-do-something.1023016/#post-4910074

Comment: I have four buttons on a userform. Three of them work on single click. Forth needs to be clicked twice.  ...  Also see .. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/activex-buttons-unresponsive-or-having-to-be-clicked-twice-to/m-p/1016865#M44598

Comment: For reference .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30881945/excel-userform-button-click-slow-response-time-when-clicked-fast  .. and .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566770/assign-on-click-vba-function-to-a-dynamically-created-button-on-excel-userform

Comment: None of the above work. One of the fixes (use getfocus instead of click) almost appears to work, but then if you switch out of that sheet then go back in, the getfocus event is fired again!

Comment: Great! Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

just run into the same problem,
I commented all

> Application.ScreenUpdating = False

> Application.ScreenUpdating = True

out.

after that button started to behave as expected, one click one call or method _click.